# Django query Count returns always 0

Tags: django, django-queryset

This is my model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In views.py

-When I try this one to count empty lastname fields:

```
People.objects.filter(lastname__isnull=True).count()
```

It returns always 0 event though there are some empty lastname fields.

Why I am getting 0, is there any problem with my code or Is there any other way to count empty fields in a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CharField` is most likely storing empty strings, not NULL

[Django docs on null field value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)

> Field.null
>   If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the
>   database. Default is False.
>
> Note that empty string values will always get stored as empty strings,
>   not as NULL. Only use null=True for non-string fields such as
>   integers, booleans and dates. For both types of fields, you will also
>   need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as
>   the null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).
>
> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField unless you have an excellent reason. If a string-based field
>   has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”:
>   NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two
>   possible values for “no data;” Django convention is to use the empty
>   string, not NULL.

Try changing your query to:

```
People.objects.filter(lastname="").count()
```

Empty is not the same as NULL. You would have needed to set your fields to have `null=True`, which as the docs suggest, is not recommended for a CharField.